# facebook fan page tab

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

Can I change facebook tab name by PHP sdk from `apps.facebook.com/XXXX/` by dynamically(with one form and one text box and one submit button).

Second is: can I create multiple tab name one at a time on the fly from `apps.facebook.com/AAAA`?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cant.

You can not change the settings of your application, which include its tab name, by any of the sdk's facebook offers.